# If $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise and $f_n \rightarrow f'$ uniformly, then does f = f'?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

I'm motivated to ask this question because of the following question.

> Consider the sequence $\{f_n\}$ defined on $[0, \pi]$ by $f_n(x) = \sin^n(x)$. Show that $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise. Use the fact that if $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of continuous functions that converges uniformly to $f$, then $f$ is continuous to show that $\{f_n\}$ is not uniformly convergent.

$f_n$ converges pointwise to $g(x)$ defined by $g(x) = 0$ if $x \neq \frac{\pi}{2}$, and otherwise $g(x) = 1$. Clearly, $g(x)$ is not continuous. Hence, $f$ cannot converge uniformly to $g$.

However, the question asked me to prove that $\{f_n\}$ is not uniformly convergent, but I have only proved that $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to $g$.

If indeed it was the case that $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise and $f_n \rightarrow f'$ uniformly, then $f = f'$, then I would be done since $f_n$ cannot converge uniformly to no other function than $g$.

But I'm not sure if this is true. Intuitively it seems true, but I might be missing something.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Limits are unique, so if for every $x$, $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ and $f_n(x) \to f'(x)$, then $f(x)=f'(x)$.  Uniformity is irrelevant.